# docker failed to initialize docker desktop is shutting down how can i fixed it

Tags: docker

I have installed a Docker update version, But  I couldn't open Docker.

The Notification is
***Docker failed to initialize docker desktop is shutting down*** how can I fixed it.

Comment: Your question talks about Docker, but you do not have a single [tag:docker] tag and a bunch of seemingly unrelated tags. Please add correct related tags.

Comment: remove all content in C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Docker

Comment: Solution: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12523#issuecomment-1029156833

Comment: @mkareshky thank you. That should be the answer here in Q3 2022. 

Fix: Manually remove this file <HOME>\AppData\Roaming\Docker\locked-directories

I additionally run C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\com.docker.backend.exe and closed it gracefully.

After that it worked for me though i haven't tried a reboot.

Edit: Yes, works after a reboot as well

Comment: remove folder "Docker" in "C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming" & remove "setting.json" in "C:\Users<YourUser>\AppData\Roaming\Docker" , fixed issue for me

Answer (score 130, accepted):

I had the same problem.
You need to enter in C:\Users<YourUser>\AppData\Roaming\Docker
Delete the file settings.json and add a new one.

After, you just need to restart the docker desktop.

Please, tell me if my answer helped you :)
[image: Example]

Comment: it is worked with me very nice, but after disable and enable hyperv

Comment: My solution was to downgrade from Docker Desktop 4 to [Docker Desktop 3](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/release-notes/3.x/).

Comment: your solution didn't fix this issue for me :(

Comment: I have looked at docker versions and see what actually has been touched by their least version which does not work. These things are normal, especially, if the engine of the software has been upgraded.
Looking through Docker versions, the latest version which has not touched the docker engine is 4.8.0. I have downloaded and works beautifully.

Comment: Only removing entire C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Docker folder fixes the problem.

Comment: Deleting that folder did fix for me but the issue has come back now a few times.... Why the heck is it happening???

Comment: Same issue, same fix. I was unable to open that settings.json file in an editor, its encoding had changed or something. After deleting it, I did not need to restart Docker manually. It reloaded and took me through starting prompts again like I'd never used Docker before.

Comment: For me, this solution was not working, so I downgraded 4.22.0 to 4.12.0 then it worked like a charm.