# Docker failed to initialize Docker Desktop is shutting down

Tags: docker, installation, docker-desktop

This question was already asked a lot, but I didn't found a solution which is working for me.
I downloaded Docker Desktop with his [guide](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/) for my windows 10 machine. After a successful installation the application does not start.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69469578/docker-failed-to-initialize-docker-desktop-is-shutting-down-how-can-i-fixed-it) solution didn't work. I deleted `settings.json` and restarted everything without success. Even reinstalling did not work. Any one has an other idea?

Edit:Reinstalling an older version (3.6.0 in my case) fixed the issue, but there has to be some other way...

[image: docker start fail]

Answer (score 1):

Stop all processes with Docker, e.g. like this:

```
# in admin mode
taskkill /F /IM wsl.exe 
taskkill /F /IM wslhost.exe 
taskkill /f /IM wslservice.exe
taskkill /f /IM "docker desktop.exe"
```

And them remove the file "settings.json".

If it doesn't help only then remove all content from the directory:

```
C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Docker
```

After that start Docker Desktop.