# Docker Desktop App is immediately 'shutting down' after launch

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

so since some days Docker Desktop is immediately shutting down after I start it manually as I always do. It says 'failed to initialize'.

After opening the Docker Desktop app, I'm receiving the following screen.
[image: Docker App starting screen]

Then after a few seconds, Docker is shutting down completely and shows me this message.
[image: failed to initialize message]

**What have I tried to solve the problem:**

- I've tried to delete the settings.json in C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Docker as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69469578/docker-failed-to-initialize-docker-desktop-is-shutting-down-how-can-i-fixed-it) question.
- I've also tried to delete the whole Docker folder in AppData.
- I've stopped / closed the Docker service, in the task manager details tab, several times.
- Lastly I've uninstalled and installed Docker Desktop again.

All of these did not help... I guess there must be some kind of conflict between Docker and another application running. Maybe someone had the same problem as me and can share his solution.

Cheers!